# Lens's diameter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

This question is asked in a famous competition in my country: "Approximately calculate the diameter of the lens which this picture is taken with.(for measurements consider lens as a flat object)" Can you please guide me for solving it it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Comment: Look. It's not a homework.Its just a question in a famous quest in my country. I just want the answer.

Comment: If you click the first link I provided, you will see how Physics.SE defines homework. If you just want an answer, you will not find it here.

Comment: OK, then will you please guide me in solving it?

Comment: If you scroll down a little further, you will see that Floris has already done quite a lot in guiding you to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key to solving this problem lies in careful observation. What can you learn from the image? You have a ruler ("close by") in focus, and points in the distance ("infinity") that are blurred. Depth of focus of a lens depends on its aperture - the bigger the lens, the more objects not in focus will be blurred.

The size of the blur can be compared to the scale of the ruler. You need to draw yourself a diagram showing how, for a given aperture and focal length of the lens, things will show up in the image plane. Perhaps you need to make assumptions about the focal length - perhaps you can figure it out from the different sizes of the things you can see.

Here is the kind of diagram you need to draw - see how far you can get with this:

[image]

Rays from the ruler are shown in green (distance to object $d_o$, distance to image plane $d_i$); the red lines are "from infinity" and show how the blur arises. The lens is the blue thing in the middle. This is obviously not to scale!

Since "homework like questions" should only get hints, you need to take the above and work with it - expand the question with your attempt, and then focus your question to a more specific concept.

It's an interesting question.